# Remove duplicates within the map function

Tags: javascript, duplicates, map-function

I want to remove duplicates within the map function and I have looked through the different posts on the internet but I am still not finding the solution.

**The JSON:**

```
"results": [
    {
        "data": {
            "labels": {
                "results": [
                    {
                        "name": "tom"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "labels": {
                "results": [
                    {
                        "name": "jerry"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "data": {
            "labels": {
                "results": [
                    {
                        "name": "tom"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
]
```

**The code:**

```
obj.results.map((items) => {
    if (items.data.labels.results.length) {
        items.data.labels.results.map((result) => {
            console.log(result.name);
        });
    }
});
```

**Result**

tom

jerry

tom

**Expected Result**

tom

jerry

**Tried this solution but didn't work**

```
obj.results.map((items) => {
    if (items.data.label.results.length) {
        items.data.label.results.map((result) => {
            console.log(Array.from(new Set(result.name)));
        });
    }
});
```

**Result from above code**

[ 't', 'o', 'm' ]

[ 'j', 'e', 'r', 'r', 'y' ]

[ 't', 'o', 'm' ]

Comment: You don't use `map` for this task. The `map` function preserves the number of elements, so at best you could map the duplicates to `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve this using [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) to get all name objects and then [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to extract the `name` field. After that a `Set` to dedupe. [`[...new Set(..)]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#remove_duplicate_elements_from_the_array) converts the Set back to an array

```js
const results = [{
    "data": {
        "labels": {
            "results": [{
                "name": "tom"
            }, {
                "name": "another name"
            }]
        }
    }
}, {
    "data": {
        "labels": {
            "results": [{
                "name": "jerry"
            }]
        }
    }
}, {
    "data": {
        "labels": {
            "results": [{
                "name": "tom"
            }]
        }
    }
}]

const res = [...new Set(results.flatMap(({data:{labels: {results}}}) => results).map(({name}) => name))]

//alternative
//const res = [...new Set(results.map(({data:{labels: {results}}}) => results).flat().map(({name}) => name))]

console.log(res)
```

Comment: getting TypeError: x.flatMap is not a function

Comment: @orbnexus whats your object name. alternatively `const res = [...new Set(x.map(({data:{results}}) => results).flat().map(({name}) => name))]` should produce the same result
`

Comment: @orbnexus lets say your oobject name is `myObject` and it has a `results` field you should do `[...new Set(myObject.results.map(({data:...`

Comment: @orbnexus also i assumed that your inner results arrays can have multiple name objects like `"results": [{"name": "tom"},{"name": "another name"}]` . this solves that case as well

Comment: also do you happen to run an older version of node or something
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap#browser_compatibility

Comment: my node is version 14

Comment: I have also updated the json and added one more node to it

Comment: @orbnexus for node 14 flatMap should work. even after adding extra node `[...new Set(x.flatMap(({data:{labels: {results}}}) => results).map(({name}) => name))]` should work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/246697/discussion-between-cmgchess-and-orbnexus).

Answer (score 2):

I would use `reduce` since it is perfect for iterating an array with an accumulative value. In this case, an object.

```js
const x = [{
    "data": {
      "results": [{
        "name": "tom"
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "results": [{
        "name": "jerry"
      }]
    }
  },
  {
    "data": {
      "results": [{
        "name": "tom"
      }]
    }
  }
]

var result = Object.values(x.reduce(function(acc, item) {
  var name = item.data.results[0].name
  // acc[name] = item;
  acc[name] = name;
  return acc;
}, {}))

console.log(result)
```